# Using Named Range and Variable to Define a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to use a named range and variable to define a range that I want to autofill and I can only get one of the named ranges to work and not the variable in my code.  The `ColLetter` variable is what is giving me trouble.  If the I omit that variable and just put `"AR"` in the range the code works it is just not dynamic.

```
Sub test()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ColLetter As Range
         lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 'Counts rows in specific column which controls how far to autofill.
         ColLetter = Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, 2)
         'Range("Notes_Start").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Notes_Start:AR" & lastRow) 'This works just is not dynamic.  The AR for column is static.
         Range("Notes_Start").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Notes_Start:ColLetter" & lastRow)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems, `Dim ColLetter As Range` should really be `Dim ColLetter As String`, your string concatenation is wrong, change `Range("Notes_Start:ColLetter" & lastRow)` to `Range("Notes_Start:" & ColLetter & lastRow)`

Comment: Thanks this fixed my code Jeanno.  Syntax got me again.  @FreeMan is right I should probably stop using letters for column references.

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful using letters to define columns in your code.

- If your active cell is `A1`, `Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, 2)`

  - yields `A$`, which is what you want.
- If your active cell is `AA1`, `Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, 2)`

  - yields `AA`. You lose the `$` and your reference is broken.

You would probably be better off using numerical references to columns:

```
Dim Col as integer
Col = ActiveCell.column
```

I'm not familiar with the `Range("Notes_Start:..."` syntax, but I believe that you could use `Range("Notes_Start").Offset(lastrow,Col)` to get what you're after. The `Offset()` may need a tweak of +1 or -1 to adjust to exactly where you need to be. Some quick trial & error will show exactly what you need to do.

You could use:

```
Dim adr() as string
Dim ColLetter as string
adr = split(ActiveCell.Address, "$")
ColLetter = adr(0)
```

But I'd still recommend using column numbers...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The "Notes_Start" is my named range which is  a single cell.  I am still getting a runtime error '1004':  AutoFill method of Range class failed.  Is this the way you intended the code below?  Sub test1()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Col As Integer
    Col = ActiveCell.Column
    lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 'Counts rows in specific column which controls how far to autofill.
    Range("Notes_Start").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Notes_Start").Offset(lastRow, Col) 'This works just is not dynamic.  The AR for column is static.
End Sub

Comment: If `Notes_Start` is a named range, you would refer to it as `Range("Notes_Start")`. I though that maybe it was a large range of cells and that the `Notes_Start:<row>, <col>` was a syntax I was unfamiliar with for referring to a cell within that named range.

Comment: What range are you trying to refer to with `Destination:=Range("Notes_Start:ColLetter" & lastRow)`

Comment: In this instance "Notes_Start" = $AR$8